# A DocuSign API call to make a health check

Tags: docusignapi

We have an API service that has hard dependency to DocuSign. So we need to quickly know whenever our configuration to DocuSign is not valid or if there is another issue connecting to DocuSign.

Initially we've developed a health indicator through Spring's Actuator: HealthIndicator and code that fetches info about user

```
@Override
public Health health() {
    UsersApi usersApi = new UsersApi(docusignClient);
    try {
        UserInformation userInformation = usersApi.getInformation(accountId, userId);

        if (userInformation == null) {
            return Health.outOfService().build();
        } else {
            return Health.up().build();
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        log.error("Failed Docusign health check", e);

        return Health.outOfService().withException(e).build();
    }
}
```

Though, this way we've reached call rate limit (1000/h) https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/introduction-changes/api-call-limits.

Is there other API call / other way to verify connection and credentials to Docusign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling the SOAP API or REST? If SOAP, Ping method can be used to determine if there's a connection to DocuSign: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/Account-Management-Service-API/Ping

If REST, a GET call to `https://{{server}}.docusign.net/restapi/service_information` can be used to check the connection.

Note that that these methods aren't authenticated, so it won't help confirm credentials are valid, but they also won't count against your call limit. How often were you calling the UserInformation method to check the connection with DocuSign?

Comment: We use Rest. Currently it is about every 30 seconds. This health check is part of the overall system health check, which includes other dependencies aswell